# Best practice location for option values for classes

Tags: php, model-view-controller, oop, global-variables

With a PHP MVC project, I have a few model classes that load data from a RESTful web service, which requires an API key.  I'd like to store the necessary API key in the central config file of my application.

To get that API key to my class, which method would be considered best?

1. Put the value in `$GLOBALS`, so it can be accessed directly within the model classes which utilize it.
2. Pass the value to the class upon instantiation.

Method #2 seems best for OOP and code reuse, but method #1 is very convenient.  I typically go with method #2, but I want to know if method #1 is generally considered to be an acceptable use of `$GLOBALS`, even in an OOP MVC environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Symfony 1.4 uses an sfConfig::get('my_value'), which is like your first option, only wrapped in an object.

[Symfony 2](http://components.symfony-project.org/dependency-injection/trunk/book/01-Dependency-Injection) uses [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) to reduce coupling, which is like your second option. Make sure you check out [this link](http://components.symfony-project.org/dependency-injection/trunk/book/01-Dependency-Injection) for a good explanation on dependency injection.

However, reducing coupling increases complexity. So, it's really a tradeoff. I think the main point is to **be consistent in your application**. Whichever method is used can be changed, so long as you're consistent in its use.

I would pick dependency injection. Not only is it easy to use if you use it all of the time, it's much more likely to lead to **reusable code**. The slowest part of a computer is the developer, so I try to build high quality, reusable components, wherever possible. I should also note that using dependency injection makes it much, much easier to build unit tests, should you choose to increase the quality and consistency of your code by adding unit tests.

Hope that helps...

Answer (score 1):

I 'd say the best here would be a third option: use a global constant.

```
define('API_KEY', 'foobar');
```

This is reasonable in the sense that the value of this constant is practically going to be unchanged during the lifetime of your application. A constant is better in that case because the value cannot be modified or overwritten through accident or malice. Plus, it does let you keep the convenience of a globally available value.

Comment: I used to do this, but switched to using `$GLOBALS` so I could do things such as put a PDO connection object in there.  `define()` only supports scalar values.  I keep my config in `$GLOBALS['config']`.  I see using an associative array in `$GLOBALS` and `define()` as functionally equivalent for my purposes.  Is there a problem with `$GLOBALS` that I am not considering?

Comment: @Brad: Well, not really if you are careful enough. We 've mentioned the two ends of the defensive simplicity/convenience range, and in the end it's about choice and the discipline to adhere to it.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use class constants and/or statics:

```
class myClass
{
    const MY_API_KEY = 'somestringofstuff';

    // Or use a static array if you need access to multiple keys

    public static $apiKeys = array(
        'dev' => 'mydevapikey',
        'prod' => 'myprodapikey'
    );
}


// Calling code
$apiKey = myClass::MY_API_KEY;

// Or

$apiKey = myClass::$apiKeys['dev'];
```